# Ruby - iterate over modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have a versioned API in Ruby-on-Rails. The different controllers and services are scoped like this:

```
class Api::V1::Navigation < Api::Navigation
```

But I have some parts of my code that need to call every version of some services. How can I iterate over them all?

I tried with this:

```
defined? eval('Api::V1')::Navigation
```

Problem is that even with an unexisting version, it still works:

```
defined? eval('Api::V24')::Navigation
=> "method"
```

How can I know if a version does exist?

Comment: You are asking whether the expression `eval(foo)` is defined. And it is: it's a method call to the method `eval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `constants`:

```
module API
  module V1
    class Navigation
    end
  end

  module V2
    class Navigation
    end
  end
end

API.constants
# => [:V1, :V2]
API.constants.include?(:V1)
# => true
API.constants.include?(:V24)
# => false
```

Comment: `api_versions = API.constants.select{|c| c.to_s.match(/^V\d+$/)}`

Answer (score 2):

This code can helps. If you use `const_defined?` method.

```
module API
end

module API::V1
  class Navigator
  end
end

module API::V2
  class Navigator
  end
end


API.const_defined?(:V1)
# => true
API.const_defined?(:V5)
# => false
```